# Jackson serializing bean with strange naming

Tags: jackson

I am using jackson 2.8.7, via spring boot 1.5.2, to serialize a bean to JSON. My class has a property with this name:

```
public String getCSystem() {
    return cSystem;
}
```

In the JSON I get a field such as:

```
{
    "csystem": "XXX"
}
```

where the "s" is lowercased. Is there any way to fix this? I've tried setting this in my `application.properties`:

```
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=LOWER_CAMEL_CASE
```

but it had no effect, probably because this is the default anyway.

So: any idea? Do I have to write a custom naming strategy?